# How to create new columns from a column value in pandas based on IDs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create new columns based on a given column value and merge the rows with same subject names within a given date, for example for a given pandas dataframe

| subject | questionid | answer | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | q1 | fa1 | 2021-02-27T |
| First | q2 | fa2 | 2021-02-27T |
| First | q3 | fa3 | 2021-02-27T |
| First | q4 | fa4 | ***2021-02-28T*** |
| Second | q1 | sa1 | 2021-02-27T |
| Second | q2 |  | 2021-02-27T |
| Second | q3 | sa3 | 2021-02-27T |
| Second | q4 |  | 2021-02-27T |

I want my final dataframe to contain columns based on `questionid` where each row contains data in each date range i.e. within 24 hours of `datetime` for a single subject.
**

> So, the final output should look like this,

**

| subject | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | fa1 | fa2 | fa3 | nan | 2021-02-27T |
| First | nan | nan | nan | fa4 | ***2021-02-28T*** |
| Second | sa1 | nan | sa3 | nan | 2021-02-27T |

Notice that the `first` subject has two rows because of different dates the data were collected on.

I was able to create columns based on the `questionid` in a new dataframe by using

`df.pivot(columns='questionid', values='answer')`

But the final dataframe looks like this,

| subject | questionid | answer | datetime | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | q1 | fa1 | 2021-02-27T | fa1 | nan | nan | nan |
| First | q2 | fa2 | 2021-02-27T | nan | fa2 | nan | nan |
| First | q3 | fa3 | 2021-02-27T | nan | nan | fa3 | nan |
| First | q4 | fa4 | ***2021-02-28T*** | nan | nan | nan | fa4 |
| Second | q1 | sa1 | 2021-02-27T | sa1 | nan | nan | nan |
| Second | q2 |  | 2021-02-27T | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| Second | q3 | sa3 | 2021-02-27T | nan | nan | sa3 | nan |
| Second | q4 |  | 2021-02-27T | nan | nan | nan | nan |

Is there an easier way without looping through the rows to create the desired output. Again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, use both `['subject', 'datetime']` as index in `pivot`:

```
(df.pivot(index=['subject', 'datetime'], columns='questionid', values='answer')
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  subject     datetime   q1   q2   q3   q4
0   First  2021-02-27T  fa1  fa2  fa3  NaN
1   First  2021-02-28T  NaN  NaN  NaN  fa4
2  Second  2021-02-27T  sa1  NaN  sa3  NaN
```

Comment: I tried the said method, but I am getting an error that says `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: @curiousElectron then you need `pivot_table` and to decide what to do with the duplicates (or add one extra level for pivoting)

Comment: @curiousElectron can you eventually update the question to explain your issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that should do it:

```
pd.pivot_table(index=['subject', 'datetime'], values='answer', columns='questionid')
```